# Can all water soluble ionic compounds conduct electricity?

Tags: solubility, ionic-compounds, conductivity

I'm taking a first year university chemistry course, and I am reading a lot of contradicting things. Some people say that ionic compounds that are soluble in water are *always* electrically conductive, others say that it *maybe* conductive.  Which one is it?

I have this problem to think about:

> Suppose that an unknown chemical compound exhibits the following properties:
>
> - it is crystalline but shows no electric conductivity in the solid state
> - it melts at $\mathrm{300^\circ C}$ and decomposes at $\mathrm{400^\circ C}$
> - the compound is soluble in water, the solution shows no electrical conductivity.
>
> What kind of chemical bond would you expect in the
>   given compound? Try to describe this type of bond in detail.

Everything screams "ionic" (high melting point, solid at room temperature, crystalline structure, non-conducting in solid form) besides the fact that it doesn't conduct in water.

Comment: It's probably stable molecular crystal.

Comment: hmm, never even heard of those in the course! are all inonic compounds then conductors in water?

Comment: Covalent molecular solids can also exhibit high melting points if the molecules are large enough and have high symmetry (they pack well into a crystalline structure). See for example [adamantane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamantane). Furthermore, simple ionic compounds usually don't decompose at such low temperatures. Lastly, I'd be quite interested to hear if there actually is such a thing as an ionic compound which dissolves in water but does not dissociate into electrolytes.

Comment: Melting points of 300 °C and above aren't unsual for organic compounds, think in terephthalic acid or trimesic acid. Both are soluble in water, but I'd expect some conductivity here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DavePhD is right! Your material is an organic compound.

In order to be soluble in water, it should have some polar substituents. I'd however exclude carboxylic acids or phenolic $\ce{OH}$ (except maybe in the proximity of a carbonyl group) since these will partly dissociate and yield to minor conductivity.

If the melting point wouldn't be that high, inositol would be a candidate.

The nucleobases thymine and uracil do show melting points in the 300 °C range and are both soluble in water.

Answer (score 1):

All soluble ionic compound conduct according to Debye-Hückel-Onsager theory.

Think of something molecular.

Comment: Oops I was only thinking of the melting point

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't say "always". But yes, and by default, ionic compounds are usually going to conduct electricity. I would study electrolytes before trying to decide these things, if you know electrolytes, the answer would be obvious to you

Comment: I don't know if you should have posted something like this as an answer. It would be really nice if you bring examples as to be the exceptions.